# Could someone tell me what's wrong with this unix script?

Tags: bash

What's wrong with this script? I was trying out substitution in Bash Shell, but got an error in the 2nd line, "command not found".

```
Date = 'date'
echo "Date is $Date"
```

Comment: Do you mean you got an error on the first line?

Comment: Spaces around the assignment...

Comment: No. in the second line.

Comment: main.sh: line 2: Date: command not found

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the first line and it works like this for me in bash:

```
Date=$(date) # or `date`
echo "Date is $Date"
```

Comment: That won't work: need to be `Date=$(date)`...

Comment: You are totally right, I didn't even think about what the script was supposed to do, I just removed the error :)

Comment: main.sh: line 2: Date: command not found

Comment: hey! this may sound stupid... but where to find the back apostrophe's on my keyboard? all i could find is '' :( @JakobLenfers

Comment: By your name I guess we have different keyboard layouts :) You can use the syntax @jasonwryan suggested, it is another way for the same functionality.

Comment: yes, thanks @JakobLenfers , Now, I'm simply using:- echo "Date is $(date)"

Comment: yes, thanks @jasonwryan , Now, I'm simply using:- echo "Date is $(date)"

Comment: @RanadeepGhosh see [why $(...) is preferred over backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: Sure, that works. But I still cannot understand why there is a problem echoing the variable like you wanted to in your post.

Comment: yes, actually I'm a new learner, and I was reading from a source, where this syntax was given, so I thought of giving it a try, couldn't understand why it didn't work for me. :( @JakobLenfers

Comment: Are you running it with bash? Try `bash main.sh`.

Comment: Yes! @JakobLenfers mentioned it in the description.

Comment: @JakobLenfers for me, the script I wrote, is now giving the output:- Date is 'date'

Comment: Yes, and with the modifications in my answer?

Comment: Yes! But, still not working, in fact, it's in turn printing out... Date is 'date' numerous times.. @JakobLenfers

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce this here. Running `bash test.sh` simply prints `Date is So 6. Sep 08:24:55 CEST 2015`, which is my correct date...

Comment: @JakobLenfers This is the error I'm getting:-  sh-4.3$ bash main.sh                                                                                                                                                            
main.sh: line 2: Date: command not found                                                                                                                                        
Today's date is

Comment: Please update your question with the updated code: using $() and no spaces arounfd the = sign. Perhaps show as what you get when you only give `date` at the commandline.